# file_get_contents method doesn't work if the file contains include coomand

Tags: php, wordpress, include, file-get-contents

I have a wordpress project. I tried to get the written content of php file with the file_get_contents, but it has got a problem, because the getting file has an include command, and this do the warning...

**I have to use the file_get_contents() method, because I use an other online API, which work with this method!**

In my file I use this file_get_contents() in the service.php:

```
$url = "http://localhost/davetips/sms_service.php";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($content);
die();
```

And here the beginning of content of the "`http://localhost/davetips/sms_service.php`":

```
<?php
// Wordpress
global $wpdb;
include 'wp-blog-header.php';
echo "test";

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

// Password constans
$option_password_text_key = 'password_storer_text';
// And more code ...
```

This php file didn't throw any warning or error, if it is run in directly from the url.
It write out the "test" message in the browser.

If I wanna get this file by file_get_contents() from the first file. I get this problem:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(`http://localhost/davetips/sms_service.php`): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in /var/www/wp-tutorial/service.php
```

If I comment out the include command, it will be ok!

So I don't know, how I should include the wp-blog-header.php in the sms_service.php...

Does anyone has got a good advise?

Comment: Are you sure `allow_url_fopen` is enabled?

Comment: Yes, it is on in the PHP ini file :)
`allow_url_fopen = On`

Comment: The warning has nothing to do with the file_get_contents, Are you sure that http://localhost/davetips/sms_service.php does exists? according to the warning message you posted it means that the requested file is not found.

Comment: Hey, :) It exists.
This file_get_contents() method works, If I comment out the include command in the getting php file!!!
So the file exists! (So, If I comment out the include command, It will find this file ;) )

Comment: Have you checked your server logs? Does going to `http://localhost/davetips/sms_service.php` via the browser give an error? Does `wp-blog-header.php` exist in the same directory as `sms_service.php` or the php include path?

Comment: Yeap, checked :) I didn't find any problem in the server logs.
Yeap, the wp-blog-header is everywhere exist ;-). But I don't know, why I have to use this wp-blog-heaser.php file where is the sms_service.php? :D
This file has to be in only where the service.php only... (at the remote address...) It is just an include... In Java everything okay, but in PHP no...